# Modify ToC page number position for two-line content entries

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, page-numbering

I'm putting together a book (using the `book` class) where each chapter is written by a different author. So each chapter will have *two* lines of text, and so will each entry on the ToC. By default, LaTeX positions the page number right aligned, and next to the **second** line of the entry (which is the author, in my case) in the ToC.

I want it to be next to the right next to the entry (not right-aligned) and on the first line (i.e. right next to the chapter title). Something like this:

```
**Contents**

Chapter 1 title blah blah   5
Author 1

Chapter 2 title blah   11
Author 2

etc...
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection %
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc} % Adds a PDF bookmark for the TOC.

{\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage}

\chapter[Chapter 1 title Blah Blah \\{\normalfont Author 1}]{Chapter 1 title Blah Blah \\ {\normalfont Author 1}} 

Chapter 1 text.

....

\chapter[Chapter 2 title Blah \\ {\normalfont Author 2}]{Chapter 2 title Blah \\ {\normalfont Author 2}} 

Chapter 2 text ..
....

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different input. Define something like `\chapterauthor{<title>}{<author>}` where you specify the chapter title and author separately. Then you have each of these components that you can manage within the TeX workflow. That's what I've done below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% \chapterauthor{<title>}{<author>}
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[2]{%
  \chapter[#1]{#1 \\ \normalfont #2}% \chapter{<title>}
  \addtocontents{toc}{% Add author entry to ToC
    \nobreak\par{\normalfont #2\par}\nobreak}%
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy % For this example

\tableofcontents

\chapterauthor{First chapter}{Author 1}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-5]

\chapterauthor{Second chapter}{Author 2}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Another section}\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

The author is printed as part of the chapter title as well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had completely forgotten of \addtocontents. That definitely answers one of my questions. As for the new command, I initially had something similar defined where I could specify author and title separately, but that caused me problem whenever I used pandoc to convert to epub(which I have to). Pandoc could not handle it, that's why I stuck to the default chapter command.